# Compiling program with ns_initparse() function C linux

Tags: c, linux, dns, bind

I have installed BIND. I am using -lresolv as paramete while compiling in gcc. But it is giving error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.3.0/../../../crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
/tmp/cck9LhAK.o: In function `resolvmx':
res.c:(.text+0x6b): undefined reference to `__ns_initparse'
res.c:(.text+0xda): undefined reference to `__ns_parserr'
res.c:(.text+0x11c): undefined reference to `__ns_sprintrr'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688895/linker-error-for-nsinitparse

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You forgot to add main.o (or main.c) to your link line.